# How to patch a module that hasn't been imported by parent package's __init__.py

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-mock

I'm trying to test a tool I'm building which uses some [jMetalPy](https://github.com/jMetal/jMetalPy) functionality. I had/have a previous version working but I am now trying to refactor out some external dependencies (such as the aforementioned jMetalPy).

## Project Code & Structure

Here is a minimalist structure of my project.

```
MyToolDirectory
  ¦--/MyTool
  ¦----/__init__.py
  ¦----/_jmetal
  ¦------/__init__.py
  ¦------/core
  ¦--------/quality_indicator.py
  ¦----/core
  ¦------/__init__.py
  ¦------/run_manager.py
  ¦----/tests
  ¦------/__init__.py
  ¦------/test_run_manager.py
```

The `_jmetal` directory is to remove external dependency on the [jMetalPy](https://github.com/jMetal/jMetalPy) package - and I have copied only the necessary packages/modules that I need.

Minimal contents of run_manager.py

```python
# MyTool\core\run_manager.py

import jmetal
# from jmetal.core.quality_indicators import HyperVolume  # old working version

class RunManager:
    def __init__(self):
      pass

    @staticmethod
    def calculate_hypervolume(front, ref_point):
        if front is None or len(front) < 1:
            return 0.
        hv = jmetal.core.quality_indicator.HyperVolume(ref_point)
        # hv = HyperVolume(ref_point)
        hypervolume = hv.compute(front)
        return hypervolume
```

Minimal contents of test_run_manager.py

```
# MyTool\tests\test_run_manager.py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, Mock, patch

from MyTool import core

class RunManagerTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.rm = core.RunManager()

    def test_calculate_hypervolume(self):
        ref_points = [0.0, 57.5]
        front = [None, None]
        # with patch('MyTool.core.run_manager.HyperVolume') as mock_HV:  # old working version
        with patch('MyTool.core.run_manager.jmetal.core.quality_indicator.HyperVolume') as mock_HV:
            mock_HV.return_value = MagicMock()
            res = self.rm.calculate_hypervolume(front, ref_points)
            mock_HV.assert_called_with(ref_points)
            mock_HV().compute.assert_called_with(front)
```

## Main Question

When I run a test with the code as-is, I get this error message:

```
E           ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MyTool.core.run_manager.jmetal'; 'MyTool.core.run_manager' is not a package
```

But when I change it to:

```python
        with patch('MyTool.core.run_manager.jmetal.core') as mock_core:
            mock_HV = mock_core.quality_indicator.HyperVolume
            mock_HV.return_value = MagicMock()
            res = self.rm.calculate_hypervolume(front, ref_points)
            mock_HV.assert_called_with(ref_points)
            mock_HV().compute.assert_called_with(front)
```

... now the test passes. What gives?!

**Why can't (or rather, how can) I surgically patch the exact class I want (i.e., `HyperVolume`) without patching out an entire sub-package as well?** Is there a way around this? There may be code in `jmetal.core` that needs to run normally.

Is the reason this isn't working only because there is no `from . import quality_indicator` statement in jMetalPy's [jmetal\core\__init__.py](https://github.com/jMetal/jMetalPy/blob/master/jmetal/core/__init__.py) ?
Because even `with patch('MyTool.core.run_manager.jmetal.core.quality_indicator)` throws:

```
E           AttributeError: <module 'jmetal.core' from 'path\\to\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\jmetal\\core\\__init__.py'> does not have the attribute 'quality_indicator'
```

Or is there something I'm doing wrong?

In the case that it is just about adding those import statements, I *could* do that in my `_jmetal` sub-package, but I was hoping to let the user default to their own jMetalPy installation if they already had one by adding this to MyTool\__init__.py:

```python
try:
    import jmetal
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    from . import _jmetal as jmetal
```

and then replacing all instances of `import jmetal` with `from MyTool import jmetal`. However, I'd run into the same problem all over again.

I feel that there is some core concept I am not grasping. Thanks for the help.